# Is it a good practice to have same column in multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

Say you have three different kinds of database entities

```
COUNTRY (TABLE)
id | name | system_field (boolean)
```

when `system_field=true` system won't allow anyone to delete that row. For e.g. out of the box system offers some countries (e.g. USA, UK etc ~ which nobody is allowed to delete)

Similarly

```
ROLE (TABLE)
id | name | system_field (boolean)
1  | Admin| true
2  |Role2 | false
```

No one is allowed to delete a role where `system_field` flag is true. Such restrictions/validations are at an application level.

Need to have such "system_field" for other types of db entities is increasing and it feels like repetition of `system_field` column in many tables. please note that these db entities aren't related to each other. Is there a better way to model such a column (`system_field`) in such a way that it can be used easily for future table as well without `ALTER`ing existing tables to add `system_field` boolean column?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. I would prefer a more descriptive name however, e.g. `is_system_generated` or `is_deleteable` (if that is the sole purpose of the column). `system_field` could mean _anything_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I can't agree more.

Comment: Also, `system_field` is self-referential. `system_tuple` or `system_row` would at least say something, but I agree that there are better names possible.

Answer (score 3):

The tables *COUNTRY* and *ROLE* represent different, unrelated domain entities.  They just happen to have a descriptive attribute of the same kind called *system_field*.

Since the entities are unrelated in terms of meaning, they should each occupy their own table as they now do and it is correct that each has a system_field column.

If the entities were conceptually related, say *CUSTOMER* and *EMPLOYEE* there might be good arguments in favor of normalizing the data representation.

Comment: I don't know about normalizing customers and employees (I'd have to see the actual data they were storing) but you are correct otherwise.

Comment: @Jeff: Yep, depends on the specific situation.  Changed "would" to "might".